Dcokerfile for django can not install sql odbc driver 17
hey guys i ran into serious problem with my Dockerfile on my Django project at first the django installation and other things goes smoothly and if I try not install odbc driver 17 everthing goes well except my database is SQL server and Django can not connect to database without ODBC driver 17
so i am trying to install ODBC17 driver to DockerFile via this code
# Use the specific Python version as a parent image
FROM python:3.10.12-slim-buster

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /winuty

# Copy your project's requirements file
COPY ./requirements.txt /winuty/

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install gunicorn
# Copy project
COPY . /winuty/

# # Collect static files
# RUN python manage.py collectstatic

# # Add and run as non-root user
# RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' winutyapp
# USER winutyapp

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl gnupg

# Add Microsoft's GPG key for the repository
RUN apt-key -sSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl -sSL https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update

# Install the ODBC driver
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17 --assume-yes
# Run gunicorn
CMD gunicorn tikuty.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000

but the main problem is we can not get the key in Dockerfile and it leads to this error
 => ERROR [web  8/11] RUN apt-key -sSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -                                 3.3s 
------                                                                                                                                        
 > [web  8/11] RUN apt-key -sSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -:                                            
1.688 Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)                                                                 
1.753 gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.                                                                                                       
------                                                                                                                                        
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-key -sSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2


could anyone help me out here ?
I have tried my Dockerfile which I shared earlier but there was no fortune in it I have read tons of articles to solve this problem but I always had the same problem the getting key and ssl key I even tried to do it straightly in microsoft official website to download and install odbc17 via curl command but it did not make any difference even the copilot and chatgpt are giving me some nonsense answers except the ways I have already tried could anybody help me out here ?
